# Does React Native’s FlatList recycles off-screen view components?

Tags: react-native

Couldn’t find any info about it in their [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist).

Comment: Recycle? Can you clarify your terminology? It doesn't unmount them behind the scenes, if that's what you mean. It does visually stop rendering them though.

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration

Comment: Thanks @BloodyMonkey!
Yes, by Recycle I mean do unmount the views (i.e., dealloc them to save memory)
This is what Android and iOS does on their components for presenting lists

How do you know it doesn’t unmount them?